# How can I get an alert-message in Webdriver Sampler for JMeter?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to log all alert messages while running JMeter Tests with Webdriver Sampler (and accept the alert boxes).
I already tried to take a screenshot and accept the alert, but it didn't work:

```
try{
    WDS.browser.switchTo().alert();
    WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium).OutputType.FILE).renameTo(new java.io.File("output/screenshot.png"));
    WDS.browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch(exception){
    WDS.log.info(exception);
}
```

[Screenshot of Sampler Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr8EW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Current version of the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) is [3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.1) which assumes [Selenium Support library version 3.14.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/3.14.0)

As of Selenium Support library version 3.14.0 you cannot take screenshots (and in fact do anything else) until the alert is present and active, so it means that you cannot take browser screenshot by means of Selenium.

If you do need the screenshot of your page with the alert you can go for [Robot.createScreenCapture() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)), the alternative code would be something like:

```
new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 2000).until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(new java.awt.Robot().createScreenCapture(new java.awt.Rectangle(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())), "png", new java.io.File("output/screenshot.png"));
WDS.browser.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your code snippet but it seems that the Webdriver waits until an alert appears and doesn't continue. I think I need something like an event listener for that. Is this possible?